# 16.04 wifi problem thinkpad 13

Tags: networking, thinkpad

My wifi is working perfectly at home. Output of `iwconfig` at home is:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"WiFi4 AH"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: AC:86:74:1D:51:4A   
          Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:80   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

However when i go to university i really struggle to get online. It says that i am connected but i am unable to load anything on my browser. If i walk around i can usually find a spot where i can connect but it seems like the signal i am receiving is weaker than others, as people with MBP's and my android phone have no problem getting wifi where i can't.

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"UniSydney"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: A4:6C:24:2E:47:D0   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=2 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:80   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

I noticed that Tx-Power is much lower, however im not really sure what this mean.

This might also be useful:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 3a
       serial: e4:b3:18:a5:6e:32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=10.244.90.191 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:279 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 54:ab:3a:ba:0d:e2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:280 memory:f1100000-f111ffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with my university and Linux. It is a well-known complaint in the physics faculty.

The solution has been to teather to android mobile which is connected to the university wifi or to use an ethernet port when available.